# Transfer a program into a logarithm formula

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I have been thinking what is the math formula for the piece of code I wrote below.

Assume there are B, D and F three positive integers, and D is smaller than F. Given D and F, the value of B would be found by the following program.

I wonder what is the formula for this. Many thanks.

```
int B = 1;
while( D < F ) {
    B = B + 1;
    F = F / 2;
}
return B;
```

Comment: $B=1+\lceil\log_2(F/D)\rceil$

Comment: @code geass its interesting that the running time of this code is also log(n).. which might help figure our similar problems in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with $B = 1$ and increment it each time the loop runs, so the final value $B$ is one more than the number of times the loop runs.

The loop divides $F$ by $2$ each time until it is at most $D$. After $k$ iterations of the loop, $F$ changes to $\lfloor F/2^k \rfloor$. So the number of times the loop runs is the smallest $k \ge 0$ such that $\lfloor F/2^k \rfloor \le D$. As $D$ is an integer, this is equivalent to $F/2^k \le D$, which in turn is equivalent to $2^k \ge F/D$ or $k \ge \log_2 (F/D)$. The smallest such integer $k \ge 0$ is therefore $\lceil \log_2(F/D)\rceil$. (If $F \le D$ is possible, we'd have to take the maximum of this and $0$.)

This means that the returned $B$ is therefore
$$B = 1 + \lceil \log_2(F/D)\rceil.$$

A note on code: despite having the formula, it may be better to keep the existing code, because floating-point operations have subtle rounding properties and may introduce error if not reasoned about carefully. In fact, the loop, involving only integer operations, may in fact run *faster* than the formula, which involves division (note that you can't do integer division $\lfloor F/D \rfloor$ here) followed by finding the floating-point logarithm, then taking ceiling, etc.

Comment: The loop will probably run much faster, because of only using integers, incrementing numbers and comparing them are very fast, and division by 2 can be done using bitshifting.

Comment: @qwr: Yes, that's what I said too.